# Does NASA have an Army and Air Force Exchange Service?

Tags: nasa, food, ground-station

Considering the relativity of military at NASA, the question here is "Does NASA have it's own [Army and Air Force Exchange Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Army_and_Air_Force_Exchange_Service) (AAFES), or does it share with the Department of Defense?"

The AAFES provides goods and services to members of the American military, so that they still have access to them even overseas.

Comment: In general, before using an acronym, it's a good idea to post the full title of whatever you're referring to.  For some things, like NASA, you don't have to, because everyone knows about NASA.  But something like AAFES is a little more unclear, so it's better to write the full title.  That goes for any time you write something, not just on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, no.  The key reason is that NASA doesn't have "bases" the way the various defense services do -- nobody lives on-site at any of the NASA centers, even the fairly remote ones.  Thus, the only services provided are typical of large office campuses: cafeteria, gift shop, etc.